# Sending a post html request using iOS Swift not working

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I have set up a payment system for my app through PayPal using both Android and IOS.

With the click of a button, the method 'payoutRequest' is called and sends the necessary information to PayPal through Firebase Functions.

The code I have works perfectly with Android but not so much with iOS.

Android's method: `payoutRequest`

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
ProgressDialog progress;

private void payoutRequest() {

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Processing your payout ...");
    progress.setMessage("Please Wait .....");
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    // HTTP Request ....
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    // in json - we need variables for the hardcoded uid and Email
    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();

    try {
        postData.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        postData.put("email", mPayoutEmail.getText().toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Request body ...
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postData.toString());

    // Build Request ...
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Your Token")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            // something went wrong right off the bat
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            // response successful ....
            // refers to response.status('200') or ('500')
            int responseCode = response.code();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                switch(responseCode) {
                    case 200:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Payout Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        break;

                    case 500:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: no payout available", Snackbar
                                        .LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                        "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

The above method sends the html request to PayPal through the Firebase Function created, see below (firebase function):

`index.js` - JavaScript file used with Firebase Functions**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

paypal.configure({
mode: 'sandbox',
client_id: functions.config().paypal.client_id,
client_secret: functions.config().paypal.client_secret
})

exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
var price  = snapshot.child('ridePrice').val();
var pushId = context.params.pushId;

return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
});


function getPayoutsPending(uid) {
return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
    if(snap === null){
        throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
    }
    var array = [];
    if(snap.hasChildren()){
        snap.forEach(element => {
            if (element.val() === true) {
                array.push(element.key);
            }
        });
    }
    return array;
}).catch((error) => {
    return console.error(error);
});
}

function getPayoutsAmount(array) {
return admin.database().ref('history').once('value').then((snap) =>    {
    var value = 0.0;
    if(snap.hasChildren()){
        snap.forEach(element => {
            if(array.indexOf(element.key) > -1) {
                    if(element.child('price').val() !== null){
                        value += element.child('price').val();
                    }
            }
        });
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}).catch((error) => {
    return console.error(error);
});
}

function updatePaymentsPending(uid, paymentId) {
return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
    if(snap === null){
        throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
    }

    if(snap.hasChildren()){
        snap.forEach(element => {
            if(element.val() === true) {
                admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history/' + element.key).set( {
                    timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                    paymentId: paymentId
                });
                admin.database().ref('history/' + element.key + '/driverPaidOut').set(true);
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
}).catch((error) => {
    return console.error(error);
});
}

exports.payout = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
return getPayoutsPending(request.body.uid)
    .then(array => getPayoutsAmount(array))
    .then(value => {
        var valueTrunc = parseFloat(Math.round((value * 0.75) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        const sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
        const sync_mode = 'false';
        const payReq = JSON.stringify({
            sender_batch_header: {
                sender_batch_id: sender_batch_id,
                email_subject: "You have a payment"
            },
            items: [
                {
                    recipient_type: "EMAIL",
                    amount: {
                        value: valueTrunc,
                        currency: "CAD"
                    },
                    receiver: request.body.email,
                    note: "Thank you.",
                    sender_item_id: "Ryyde Payment"
                }
            ]
        });

        return paypal.payout.create(payReq, sync_mode, (error, payout) => {
            if (error) {
                console.warn(error.response);
                response.status('500').end();
                throw error;
            }
            console.info("payout created");
            console.info(payout);
            return updatePaymentsPending(request.body.uid, sender_batch_id)
        });
    }).then(() => {
        response.status('200').end();
        return null;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
 });
```

When I run the above code in Android, it works and does all it should but the below method isn't working for IOS (same index.js file used for both platforms).

iOS's method: `payoutRequest`:

```
func payoutRequest() {

    print("payoutRequest")

    // Progress View
    self.progress.progress = value
    self.perform(#selector(updateProgressView), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)

    let email = txtPayoutEmail.text!

    let url = "https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/payout"

    let params : Parameters = [
        "uid": self.uid! as String,
        "email": email
    ]

    let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Your Token",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]

    let myData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    print("data: \(String(describing: myData))")

   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in

        //print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        //print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful")
            let parsedObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData!, options: .allowFragments)
            print("parsed: \(parsedObject)")

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Also the following url is not completely accurate for privacy concerns.
https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/payout (myapp) is not name of the app

I have narrowed down the issue to the actual method in iOS - `payoutRequest` is not sending the post html request as it should.

What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After running the code (payoutRequest()) below is the print() statement:
** name of app is blacked out **

[image: print statement]

Also, if I go to my PayPal developer account, go into the Dashboard and click on Notifications, I should get a notification for the following:

- payment received in the main account (ok)
- payment received from the riders email account (ok)
- payment paid out to the driver (none)
- mass payment to driver (none)

see:
[image]

Comment: Is `payoutRequest` being run, but not calling the HTTP method? What is the output of your `print()` statements?

Comment: @halfer Yes, when run, it sends the info to the firebase function and all looks good but when I check for notifications that the payout has been sent the UserX, no notification in PayPal. The print statements are all successful, but again no notification in PayPal

Comment: see Edit for print() statements

Comment: Right, so all your HTTP calls are being made. So, where do they go? What is `cloudfunctions.net` - is that a PayPal domain? If not, you will need to add logging to the app there, if it is under you control, to see why a call to PayPal from there is failing. If that is a PayPal domain, then would you need to contact tech support to see why an apparently successful call is not producing the result you expect?

Comment: cloud functions.net is from firebase when you create a firebase function after hosting a domain in firebase.  The index.js file above is the javascript file to connect my data with PayPal.  Once run, it should send see email notifications in the Dashboard in PayPals developer site (developer.paypal.com).  I have contacted PayPal and they can't help me.  Its working for Android, just not IOS (payoutRequest)

Comment: In what way could PayPal not help? From what you say, I think `cloudfunctions.net` are not under their control. Thus, which function is calling PayPal directly?

Comment: Payout Request()

Comment: No, that's your function. Which (HTTP) function is calling PayPal? `Alamofire.request`?